# Which one is correct? help me

Tags: vocabulary

Many of useless time-waster are irresolute and often hesitant. or

Many of whom waste their time for nothing are irresolute and often hesitant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Many of useless time-waster are irresolute and often hesitant.

Time-waster in this context should be plural so that it agrees with "many" and "are", and as J.R.♦ suggests in the comment that it should be "many useless time-wasters" instead of "many of useless time-wasters"  the word "of" here should be removed; therefore, it should be like this to be correct.
[Reference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96806/many-books-vs-many-of-books)

> Many useless **time-wasters** are irresolute and often hesitant.

And for this case:

> Many of whom waste their time for nothing are irresolute and often hesitant.

It should be "who waste their time for nothing" because "whom" in this position would mean that the phrase is an object, but you need a noun like "people"  before that phrase in order to make it sounds right. Thus, it should be like this:

> Many **people who** waste their time for nothing are irresolute and often hesitant.

And for the question:

> Which one is correct?

I would say that both of the sentences that I fixed here are correct. You can use either one because they have almost the same meaning. The only difference here is that time-wasters in the first sentence are useless.